# JAXB add/remove node from existing XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have the following code to Create an XML and also read through it,
What I want to achieve is, remove a particular node on basis of it's ID.

**Class employee.java -**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jaxb.examples.list;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee 
{
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double income;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public double getIncome() {
        return income;
    }
    public void setIncome(double income) {
        this.income = income;
    }
}
```

**Class Employees.java -**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jaxb.examples.list;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "employees")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees 
{
    @XmlElement(name="employee")
    private List<Employee> employees = null;

    private Integer size;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

**Class TestEmployeeMarshing.java -**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jaxb.examples.list;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class TestEmployeeMarshing 
{
    static Employees employees = new Employees();
    static 
    {
        employees.setEmployees(new ArrayList<Employee>());

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setId(1);
        emp1.setFirstName("John");
        emp1.setLastName("Doe");
        emp1.setIncome(10000.0);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setId(2);
        emp2.setFirstName("Jane");
        emp2.setLastName("Doe");
        emp2.setIncome(20000.0);

        Employee emp3 = new Employee();
        emp3.setId(3);
        emp3.setFirstName("Bacon");
        emp3.setLastName("Butter");
        emp3.setIncome(30000.0);

        Employee emp4 = new Employee();
        emp4.setId(4);
        emp4.setFirstName("Pepparoni");
        emp4.setLastName("Pizza");
        emp4.setIncome(40000.0);

        employees.getEmployees().add(emp1);
        employees.getEmployees().add(emp2);
        employees.getEmployees().add(emp3);
        employees.getEmployees().add(emp4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException 
    {
        marshalingExample();
        System.out.println("************************************************");
        unMarshalingExample();
    }

    private static void unMarshalingExample() throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        employees = new Employees();
        employees = (Employees) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("G:/xml/employees.xml") );
        List<Employee> tempEmp=   employees.getEmployees();


        for (int i = 0; i < tempEmp.size(); i++) {

            if(tempEmp.get(i).getId().equals(3)){
                System.out.println("ID equals 3");
                tempEmp.remove(i);
            }
        }

        marshalingExample();

    }

    private static void marshalingExample() throws JAXBException
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(employees, System.out);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(employees, new File("G:/xml/employees.xml"));
    }
}
```

**I need to remove the Node with ID 1 and add a new Node.**

Comment: So? What is keeping you from doing it? Remove the item with id=1 from the list, add your replacement element and set the list back to Employees. Done.

Comment: BTW: you never read the contents of the fxml to your `static employees` field but read it to a local variable instead. This way you never modify the object that is written to the output file. Furthermore this code doesn't work, if multiple `Employee`s can have the same `id`, since it would skip the second of 2 adjacent `Employee`s with a `id` of 3. If `id`s are unique, a `break;` statement should be inserted to the `if` body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You best seperate the code reading the data from code using it, e.g. by putting the parts of the code to different methods. Furthermore it would be more convenient to pass the data to the marshalling method to make it easier to reuse instead of relying on the `static` `employees` field to pass the data.

The `List` in a `Employees` instance can be modified just like any other modifiable `List`:

```
private static Employees unmarshalFromFile(String fileName) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return (Employees) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(fileName));
}

private static void marshalToFile(Employees data, String fileName) throws JAXBException
{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, new File(fileName));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    Employees data = unmarshalFromFile("G:/xml/employees.xml");

    Integer removeId = 1;
    data.getEmployees().removeIf((Employee emp) -> removeId.equals(emp.getId()));

    Employee newEmployee = ...
    data.getEmployees().add(newEmployee);

    marshalToFile(data, "G:/xml/employees.xml");
}
```

---

`removeIf` was added in java 8, but you can also do this in earlier versions by iterating through the list:

```
Iterator<Employee> iterator = data.getEmployees().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (removeId.equals(iterator.next().getId())) {
         iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it remove the entire Node that contains the ID 1, how do I do this in Java 7?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje You could e.g. use a `Iterator` to remove elements matching your criterion (added code to the answer).

Comment: what is removeId ? It's saying removeId cannot be resolved

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje The `Integer` local variable as defined in the java 8 version using `removeIf`

Comment: Can you check my updated code of the last file? The if condition is getting satisfied but, node is not getting removed.